# Header files for library Android

Tags: android, linux, header, shared

I find shared library(.so) in Android my device. And I want use exports functions from it. But how I understand, I need header files for this library. Where I can find it on device? What dirrectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the headers won't be available on the device.

As they are only needed to link against the library not for running the program normally they aren't contained in the system image on your device.

You might want to take a look into the headers that come with the NDK if the header you are looking for is contained there. (see: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

If it isn't it is not part of the libraries google wants you to use as it is not considered to belong to the set of libraries google intends to keep stable.

Nevertheless you'll be able to fetch the required headers from the sources belonging to the android version running on your device in this case. (see: http://source.android.com/)

It might be possible those libraries won't be available any more after the next system upgrade then but that's especially the point about headers and libraries **not** included.

It's only guarenteed the libraries included in the NDK will available.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I use exports function from library without headers?

Comment: The problem is, that without knowing the functions signature (which is the reason why you need the header) you really can't. Which libraries headers are you looking for? I mean what is the name of the .so file?